# How to install stockfish on winBoard 4.4.5?

Tags: engines, stockfish

I want to install stockfish to winBoard 4.4.5. But winBoard 4.4.5 doesn't seem to have the same protocol as stockfish. Is there a way to do it on windows 10? I would like to install the latest version of stockfish to winBoard 4.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stockfish supports the UCI protocol, Winboard supports the Xboard (or CECP) protocol. What you're looking for is a Winboard to UCI adapter, that sits between Winboard and Stockfish and does the translations between the two protocols.

The other alternative is using a chess GUI that supports UCI, e.g. Arena, ChessX, scid. even give Tarrasch a try.

Comment: It looks like Polyglot is the way to connect Winboard to UCI engines. It's being retired from Winboard, but should still be part of a Winboard installation. See here: https://www.chessprogramming.org/PolyGlot -- if the polyglot files aren't part of the Winboard install, I'd suggest downloading an older version of Winboard (Jan 2018 or earlier)